# Alternate approach to using dataframe filter method

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Assume we have a dataframe like so:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
A    |  B   |  C
D    |  F   |  C
G    |  H   |  I
Z    |  X   |  V
Q    |  R   |  V
```

Right now, for example I need to split the dataframe by unique Col3 values, such that I get DataFrame 1 like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
A    |  B   |  C
D    |  F   |  C
```

Dataframe2 like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
G    |  H   |  I
```

Dataframe3 like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
Z    |  X   |  V
Q    |  R   |  V
```

Right now I have a list of these unique col3 values and I am looping through them to filter the dataframe, like this (pseudocode):

```
list = C,I,V
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
processDF = dataframe.filter(col3=list(i))
process(processDF)
}
```

This doesn't seem like a good approach because I am scanning the initial dataframe first, filtering it by values and then processing that dataframe, then go back to scanning the initial dataframe for the second element in the list and then process that dataframe, and so on.
Is there another way where spark can simultaneously create these dataframes while scanning all in one go, leading to a performance improvement.

Comment: My suggestion would be to go with groupBy or Window.partitionBy. It really depends on why are you saparating the dataframe with distinct values in col3. Your approach won't be suitable in a distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked for DataFrame.

**Update**

```
scala> case class test(col1: String, col2: String, col3: String)
defined class test

scala> val listoftest = List(test("G", "H", "I"), test("A", "B", "C"), 
                             test("D", "F", "C"), test("Z", "X", "V"), 
                             test("Q", "R", "V"))
listoftest: List[test] = List(test(G,H,I), test(A,B,C), test(D,F,C), 
                              test(Z,X,V), test(Q,R,V))

scala> print(listoftest)
List(test(G,H,I), test(A,B,C), test(D,F,C), test(Z,X,V), test(Q,R,V))


scala> val df = sc.parallelize(listoftest).toDF
scala> df.rdd.groupBy(r => r.get(2))
res12: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Iterabl[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])]   
= ShuffledRDD[13] at groupBy at <console>:31

scala> res12.collect.foreach(x => println(x))
(I,CompactBuffer([G,H,I]))
(V,CompactBuffer([Z,X,V], [Q,R,V]))
(C,CompactBuffer([A,B,C], [D,F,C]))
```

Comment: Two questions for clarification, what is listoftest and what does r.get(2) return

Comment: Also groupBy is an expensive operation so seems like it would a performance hit if I went with the groupBy approach rather than the approach I have.

Comment: Your approach is completely wrong for big data. You are assuming that dataframe contains data. That is wrong it doesn't contain any data. It represents the source of the data and when any action is performed on it, then it works on the data in a distributed way depending on the hardware setup we have. I updated the answer with the case class.